# Restart needed after installing .NET Core Runtime and SDK?

Tags: asp.net-core, production-environment, asp.net-core-2.0

We're about to deploy a netcore 2.0 application on production, but we need to install .NET Core Runtime and SDK first. Is a restart needed for the installation to take effect? Since it's production, we don't want that to happen.

Comment: No it's not. follow [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis?tabs=aspnetcore2x)

Comment: Is your question trying to say “we have no staging environment and I have no idea how this thing is going to blow up in production”. Don’t worry, been there, done that, it will be fine. Just don’t directly deploy your site to production from VS, because that WILL need an app pool restart. Don’t even ask me how I know that. :-)

Comment: Luckily we didn't deploy straight from VS. Ok, I won't ask how do you know that, instead I will ask "what happened"? :D

Answer (score 6):

We installed the following from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows)

1. x64 Installer (SDK)
2. x64 Installer (Runtime)
3. Windows Server Hosting (Runtime)

There was no need to restart the machine and nothing blew up (:

Answer (score 3):

If you are creating a Windows Service using the .NET Core SDK (Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices) and deploying it in the target machine you need a restart (atleast a log off depending on the application you are running). Here is what happens.

1. Install .NET Core Runtime
2. Deploy a windows service.
3. You will notice that the command line in the windows service will be "dotnet "
4. Start the service. It will fail because it cannot find the tool "dotnet".
5. This is because the service control manager (services.msc) is not aware of the dotnet command being added to the path. So you can either do a log off (or)restart to make sure things work.

Answer (score 2):

You could just install **Windows Server Hosting Bundle** without SDK on your production machine (actually it should be).

But then you'll get 502.3 error, and you could add a element as follows into {YourProject}.csproj file, and then it'll work like a charm.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Ref: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/13542

Answer (score 0):

With respect to either:

- .NET 6.0 Desktop Runtime (v6.0.2) - Windows x64 Installer [Link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-desktop-6.0.2-windows-x64-installer)
- .NET 6.0 Runtime (v6.0.2) - Windows x64 Installer [Link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-6.0.2-windows-x64-installer)

... a reboot is not required.

I didn't have time to test:

- ASP.NET Core 6.0 Runtime (v6.0.2) - Windows Hosting Bundle Installer [Link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-6.0.2-windows-hosting-bundle-installer)
- ASP.NET Core 6.0 Runtime (v6.0.2) - Windows x64 Installer [Link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-6.0.2-windows-x64-installer)

... but agree with @MuqeetKhan that you should ideally have both a dev && testing lower environment before performing a production install.  (*Though, I also understand with smaller co's, that due to constraints & battles lost; this may not be possible*.)