# In sever restart required after installing .NET Core Runtime and SDK?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

In server already other app published so when I published my asp.net core app getting error so I installed NET Core Runtime and SDK but not restart server due to other app running but after installing runtime and SDK issue not solved so confused restart required or not?

Comment: Did restarting make it work?

Comment: I don't know that's why asking it's required or not

Comment: The installer itself will tell you if restart is needed. Restart is needed only if some files are currently in use. If you close the applications that use those files, you won't have to restart. The installer will even tell you which applications lock needed files

Comment: so this may mean that your original error does not involve the runtime or there are still other errors not involving the runtime at all. Try digging into the error detail instead of guessing around like this.

Answer (score 0):

No, generally it should not: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ecd4223d-7099-4e38-a2d0-27099e7c7dda/net-core-30-after-installation-does-it-require-reboot?forum=vsx

> In general, we do not need to restart PC and if you install the official version,you do not need to  do any restart. If you install the preview of .Net Core 3.0, you should check this option(Tools--Options-->Environment-->Preview Features-->use previews of the .net core sdk(require restart)) and then restart VS.

There is a mention here: [Restart needed after installing .NET Core Runtime and SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47438318/restart-needed-after-installing-net-core-runtime-and-sdk) about windows services needing at least a log off, but in general there should be no need.

Answer (score 0):

The installer itself will tell you if a restart is needed. Restart is needed only if some files are currently in use. If you close the applications that use those files, you won't have to restart.

The installer will even tell you which applications lock needed files and even offer to close them during installation. A restart is only needed if you *can't* stop those applications during installation.